# Android get global android user interaction listener

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, ontouchlistener, android-windowmanager

I have a app which sends intent to a pdfviewer whenever a button is clicked.

Now my app is like a KIOSK app and one of its requirement is that whenever user leaves android/ do no interaction with it for some seconds i have to fire intent to my KIOSK app again.

Thats what the problem is listening touch inside my app is no issue. **But how can i listen for touch event for all android phone**.

What i have tried is **WindowManager** and adding a empty view on window manager but the problem is either it hit my view click event or it hits pdfapp scroll event it does not hit both.

so any ideas if we could solve this WindowManager touch problem or any better way of solving this problem?

Comment: You could try to use the `ViewGroup` to manage touch events. https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT do you mean that i add viewgroup in windowmanager? and then fire intent to pdfviewer to get touch events on pdfviewer or on screen?

Comment: What is your pdfviewer? Does it give you the permission or the open interface to send the touch back to you?

Comment: no! actually pdfviewer is any pdf app which shows pdf its a third party app and its upto client choice which ever he wants to open pdf with. so i have no whatsoever interaction with that app.

Comment: If there is no interaction, how do you want the pdfviewer response whenever a button is clicked?

Comment: No! the scenario is whenever a button is clicked it sends a intent to pdfviewer. so pdfviewer displays pdf in it. after that I have no interaction with pdfviewer!

Problem is simple yet so complicated. i just want to close pdfviewer if user do not interact with the device for lets see 30 seconds. and pdfviewer is a third party app. :(